# Is it possible to calculate confidence Level or p-value?

Tags: statistics

I have a very basic question about p-value and confidence level. Assume a company had a survey on 3 of their products about if their customers like those products.

- Product A (1000 customers participated in the survey)    80% like
  20% dislike
- Product B (200 customers participated in the survey)    90% like
  10% dislike
- Product C (3000 customers participated in the survey)    70% like
  30% dislike

Is it valid to say product B is better than others even if less customers participated? If so, can we calculate p-value and confidence level for such claim? And how?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any specific relation to python, machine-learning or scikit-learn. Please limit you tags to those, which are actually meaningful to help you to address the right people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick approximate way is to combine you not A products together and do a fisher test, I do the test in R:

```
M = matrix(c(800,200,180,20,2100,900),ncol=3)
colnames(M) = LETTERS[1:3]
rownames(M) = c("Like","Dislike")
          A   B    C
Like    800 180 2100
Dislike 200  20  900
```

Then you regroup them:

```
newM = cbind(M[,2],rowSums(M[,-2]))
colnames(newM) = c("B","notB")

          B notB
Like    180 2900
Dislike  20 1100
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  newM
p-value = 3.498e-09
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.131986 5.751961
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  3.412732
```

Then you get back the odds ratio and c.i, The odds ratio is calculated as p(like product / dislike | B) / p(like product / dislike | not B). You can roughly estimate it like:

```
(180/20)/(2900/1100) = 3.413793
```

You can do the above in python, to get confidence interval, you can use something like a logistic regression, and we test whether B is different from the rest:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({"Product":["A","A","B","B","C","C"],
                   "Response":["Like","Dislike","Like","Dislike","Like","Dislike"],
                  'Counts':[800,200,180,20,2100,900]})
```

We need to stack it up to get a 2D array:

```
data.endog = np.array(df['Counts']).reshape(3,2)

array([[ 800,  200],
       [ 180,   20],
       [2100,  900]])

data.exog = sm.add_constant(np.array([0,1,0]))

array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 0.]])
```

In the last part, we set the coefficient of B to be 1, and others be 0, so we are modeling how different is B from the others. Now fit the model:

```
mdl = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog,family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
mdl.summary()

        coef    std err z       P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
const   0.9694  0.035   27.376  0.000   0.900   1.039
x1      1.2278  0.238   5.151   0.000   0.761   1.695
```

It gives you a similar estimate, the coefficient is 1.2278, and to convert it to odds ratio, you do `np.exp(1.2278) = 3.41371110`. And you have also the p-values and confidence interval.

Answer (score 1):

From my basic understanding, the p-Test (or check of the NULL hypothesis) only relates to a *single* randomized experiment. However, your question suggest no relation between all three hypotheses. It is simply not one joint experiment but three separate, so no way for you to check the significance between those surveys. You may read up [here](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/walras/custom/300/351B/notes/glo_07.htm#pvalue).

However, what you can do is to check if the result of one of the surveys is significant. E.g. Hypothesis: People like Product B.

Chi-square value:
x^2 = Σ((o-e)^2/e), o: observed value, e: expected value

People can only choose to like (1) or dislike (0) it, so our expected value is 0.5.

x^2(like) = 0.8*200((1-0.5)^2/0.5) = 80

Now, you need to define a significance-threshold. Usually 0.05 is taken. And to get your p-value, we need to look into smart books with tables, which tell you what chi-square value (with the number of degrees of freedom, in our case 1) belongs to which p-value.

[image: chi-square distribution table]

So our hypothesis that people like the product turns out to be 80 > 3.84, which supports the hypothesis.
Anyway, the calculation is quite trivial in your case, but hopefully, you get the idea. You my also want to have a look [here](http://web.csulb.edu/~msaintg/ppa696/696stsig.htm#4)) for a better explanation than I can give.